# Achieving tombstoning in Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a KStream with key value pairs that are grouped by key. Every key should be unique, and the only reason why it might not be is as the same key is streamed with a null as value.

In my streams application I need to filter out all the same keys if the value of on of the records is null (tombstone). How do I get started?

```java
KStream<Key, Value> table = builder.stream(kafkaProperties.getTopicName());
// If key exists multiple times, check for null value and if found
// remove / ignore record
```

So when  it needs to stay, but when   the complete key with all values need to be thrown away.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite tricky to achieve. Data is processed linearly, and thus you would need to buffer all key-value pairs in a state store, eg, using a `transform()`. You would insert each input key-value pair into the key-value store. If you receive a `null` value, you can delete it from the store.

The difficult part is, to decide/know that there won't be any `null`-value for a key in the future. How to determine this, depends on your overall setup, and there is no generic answer. If you can make the decision at some point that a key-value pair in the store cannot have a future tombstone, you can send it downstream and also delete it from the store.